# Снятие обработчиков события DOM элементов

Tags: javascript, dom, события

Стоит ли снимать обработчик на событие когда DOM-элемент удаляется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы потом будете создавать элемент с таким же ID, то да, стоит снять обработчик.
Если же при удалении объекта, вы знаете, что потом не будете создавать этот объект с таким же ID, то можете не добавлять себе головной боли и не удалять события к элементу.

Comment: Не имеет значения id элемента. У *каждого* элемента в дереве *свой* уникальный идентификатор. Обработчик вешается на конкретный элемент, при удалении его из дерева сбрасывается и обработчик, [пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/1htLan5b/2/)